# ServerSocket issue with jre 1.6 & 1.7 , allowing to create two socket for same port

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I am able to create two ServerSocket with same port number.

Run two ServerSocket program in jre 1.6 & 1.7.

anybody faced same problem?

Comment: Is this a problem? or are you asking if this is ok?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are doing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please , consider that providing code or configuration snipets would help us to answer you.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567361/several-tcp-servers-on-the-same-port.

Comment: @jop - on the evidence provided in the Question, I agree.

Comment: Example: create ServerSocket using port number 3500 run using jre 1.6. run another program to create ServerSocket using port same port (3500) using jre 1.7. second process should throw exception "Address already in use". but another process is allowed create socket. bug in jre 1.7?